# Quotient remainder theorem variation proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

> let $a, b \in \Bbb \setminus \{0\}$. Prove that there exist unique $q, r \in \Bbb Z$ such that $a=bq+r$ and $-\frac {|b|} 2 < r < \frac {|b|} 2$.

I have tried so many things, yet I just can't get it to work. My main push has been by breaking it up into two cases, $-\frac {|b|} 2 < r < 0$ and $0 < r < \frac {|b|} 2$, then trying the proof like you normally do for the original quotient remainder theorem by using the division algorithm theorem. However, this doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I could solve this?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ..."and $\;-|b|/2\;$ ..." **what** ?

Comment: You can prove this directly, but if you already have a proof that there are $q'$, $r'$ such that $a=bq'+r'$ where $0\le r'\lt |b|$, you can then modify the $q'$ and $r'$ appropriately if necessary.